# Java Netty: memory leak problem with DefaultChannelHandlerContext

Tags: java, ssl, memory-leaks, netty

Hi I have a memory leakage problem and i can't find any solution. My server code:

```
 bootstrap.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                    SSLEngine engine = engineCreator.createSSLEngine(credentials);
                    if (engine == null) {
                        throw new Exception("Can't create SSLEngine");
                    }
                    socketChannel.pipeline().addFirst("ssl", new SslHandler(engine));

                    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast("Object-decoder", new ObjectDecoder(
                            ClassResolvers.softCachingConcurrentResolver(
                                    Message.class.getClassLoader())));
                    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast("Object-encoder", new ObjectEncoder());

                //another pair of handles
                }
            })
            .option(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT)
            .childOption(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT);
```

code for EngineCreator:

```
 private static SSLEngine sslEngine = null;

public SSLEngine createSSLEngine(Credentials credentials) {
    try {
        if(sslEngine == null){
            sslEngine = getSSLContext(credentials).createSSLEngine();
            sslEngine.setUseClientMode(false);
            sslEngine.setNeedClientAuth(true);
        }

        return sslEngine;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private SSLContext getSSLContext(Credentials credentials) throws Exception {
    InputStream keyStoreInputStream = new FileInputStream(credentials.getKeyStorePath());
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    keyStore.load(keyStoreInputStream, credentials.getKeyStorePassword().toCharArray());
    keyStoreInputStream.close();

    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, credentials.getKeyStorePassword().toCharArray());

    TrustManager[] trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{
            new ReloadableX509TrustManager(credentials)
    };
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagers, null);
    return sslContext;
}

class ReloadableX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
    private final String trustStorePath;
    private X509TrustManager trustManager;
    private long listTimeModTrust;
    private final Credentials credentials;

    public ReloadableX509TrustManager(Credentials credentials) throws Exception {
        this.credentials = credentials;
        this.trustStorePath = credentials.getTrustStorePath();
        reloadTrustManager(credentials);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws 
        CertificateException {
        if (checkTimeTruststore()) {
            try {
                reloadTrustManager(credentials);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String username = x509Certificates[0].getSubjectDN().getName().split("CN=")[1].split(",")[0];
        x509Certificates[0].checkValidity();
        trustManager.checkClientTrusted(x509Certificates, s);
        x509Certificates[0].checkValidity();
    }


    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws 
         CertificateException {
      //            trustManager.checkServerTrusted(x509Certificates, s);
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }

    private void reloadTrustManager(Credentials credentials) throws Exception {
        listTimeModTrust = new File(trustStorePath).lastModified();
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(trustStorePath);
        try {
            trustStore.load(in, credentials.getTrustStorePassword().toCharArray());
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

        TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
        for (int i = 0; i < trustManagers.length; i++) {
            if (trustManagers[i] instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                trustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[i];
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException("No X509TrustManager in TrustManagerFactory");
    }

    private boolean checkTimeTruststore() {
        boolean isNewVersion = false;
        File file = new File(trustStorePath);
        Long lastTime = file.lastModified();
        if (lastTime != listTimeModTrust) {
            isNewVersion = true;
        }
        return isNewVersion;
    }

}
```

My truststore have 2k ceritificate inside. Heap dump:
[screen from eclipse memory leak plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e36ih.jpg)

Currently, after a couple of days of server operation, OutOfMemoryException occurs and the server is down. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem may be that you create a new `SslContext` object per connection. You should create it once and then share it.

Comment: The problem is that SSLContext must be created for every connection. 
I use SSLContext and not SslContext are two different classes.

Comment: I don't think thats true... SSLEngine must be created per connection SSLContext not (at least from looking at your code)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered running the memory leak detector?
https://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html

If the issue isn't the sslContext, I suspect it might be in `ObjectDecoder` or `ObjectEncoder` if you are not releasing the `ByteBuf` when you are done with it.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."